# how to split variable data from string using C#

Tags: c#

Could someone please help meto improve this part of code?

The string is something like this: **Current Hourly Price (HOEP): $20.09/MWh (2.01¢/kWh)**. this is one line on website where data of 20.09 and 2. 01 changes within time

```
static void get_HOEP(string web)
{
    int x = web.IndexOf("Current Hourly Price");
    ...
}
```

I want just to display something like: **Current Hourly Price:    2.01   ¢/kWh**

Thanks for help

Comment: If you know what the syntax of the input is you could use regular expressions. Is the syntax fixed?

Comment: Why not use a regular express to pull the parts you want?

Comment: I've run your code and it will display 'Current Hourly Price: 2.01 ¢/kWh' for your input string if you change Substring(x,100) to Substring(x)

Comment: You should be more specific about the input expression. Does it always start with `"Current Hourly Price"`? Does it always come in the same form: `"AA BB CC (DDDD): EEEE (FFFF)"`? Can it have different units in the last parentheses? Try showing more than one test input, to clarify how the program should behave in other cases, possibly some "edge cases" with "the worst king of input you could get". Having only one (specific) example is often insufficient when solving computer problems.

Comment: thanks!  this program reads reads the current price from a website every  1 s. For this reason I didn't use the regular expression ...

Comment: @make - For what reason?

Comment: @make, compile the regular expression and store it in a variable, that way evaluation is relatively quick.

Comment: because price changes within time and my program needs to displays this data every time is changed ... thanks!

Comment: @make why is this a probem, I didn't mean store the result of the replace, I meant store the compiled regex itself. i.e. use the RegexOptions.Compiled in the regular expression constructor.  Then you can just keep calling the replace function on the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex, result will be in the variable result.

```
var source="Current Hourly Price (HOEP): $20.09/MWh (2.01¢/kWh)";
var regex=new Regex(@"Current Hourly Price \(HOEP\): \$\d+\.\d\d/MWh \((\d+\.\d\d)¢/kWh\)");
var result=regex.Replace(source,"Current Hourly Price $1 ¢/kWh");
```

--EDIT-- Full Class Version

```
public static class PriceParser {

  private const string MATCH_STRING = @"Current Hourly Price \(HOEP\): \$\d+\.\d\d/MWh \((\d+\.\d\d)¢/kWh\)";
  private const string REPLACE_STRING = @"Current Hourly Price $1 ¢/kWh";
  private static readonly Regex regex=new Regex(MATCH_STRING,RegexOptions.Compiled);
  private static readonly Regex entirePageRegex=new Regex(string.Format("^.*{0}.*$",MATCH_STRING),RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.Singleline);

  public static void get_HEOP1(string web) {
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(web,REPLACE_STRING));
  }

  public static void get_HEOP2(string web) {
    Console.WriteLine(entirePageRegex.Replace(web,REPLACE_STRING));
  }
}
```

`PriceParser.get_HEOP1(web)` simply replaces the match in the search string

`PriceParser.get_HEOP2(web)` replaces the entirity of web with the replacement string

Comment: thanks! If you look at question , you'll see that 20.09 and 2.01 changes within time. So, it wouldn't work this way ... thanks!

Comment: you want to mean probably Regex.Match? Isn't it?

Comment: @make - What do you mean they change within time? create the regex somewhere and keep it in a field/variable and then everytime you want to use it use the last line of the answer:  result will contain the converted text

Comment: change within time (i.e. according to the market's demand)  ... so 20.09 and 2.01  are not constant , but variable . thanks!

Comment: @make So why can't you use the regex replace?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work can you provide proper examples because it works find when I test it in LinqPad

Comment: @make I've updated the answer with a full class for you to use.  In what way does this not work?

Comment: thanks for all replies ... because var source changes every 1 munite

Comment: @make Why exactly is that a problem, you just call the function when it changes, I really don't get why you have a problem?

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help! Now I got your idea ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of unanswered questions, but you could simply do something like this. Assuming of course that the format always stays the same. :)

```
        string[] split = web.Split('(');

        string result = "Current Hourly Price: " + split[2].Remove(split[2].Length-1);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I would recommend though that you go with something cleaner, like using a compiled regex. There are many ways to improve the performance over a regex, and it's easier to update in case the format for example changes for some reason.

Comment: I believe that the `web` parameter contains the entire web page (HTML). This is why OP decided to take a small chunk (`web.Substring(x, 100);`). Apart from this, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! however it doesn't work this way ...<br> Yes! it contains html

Comment: Ah yea, after looking over the original code that makes more sense. ;) I thought it was an odd question.^^

Comment: If you are parsing a whole webpageI would personally go with something like Bob Vale recommended. You could break up the whole page with logic, but it seems like more effort than it would be worth. You have to consider that the webpage may change at some point, and updating the logic when that happens isn't always the easiest.